# Capture console exit C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, console, exit

I have a console application that contains quite a lot of threads.  There are threads that monitor certain conditions and terminate the program if they are true.  This termination can happen at any time.

I need an event that can be triggered when the program is closing so that I can cleanup all of the other threads and close all file handles and connections properly.  I'm not sure if there is one already built into the .NET framework, so I'm asking before I write my own.

I was wondering if there was an event along the lines of:

```
MyConsoleProgram.OnExit += CleanupBeforeExit;
```

Comment: I know this is a very late comment but you don't really need to do that if "closing files & connections" is the only thing you want to do as cleanup. Because Windows already closes all handles associated with a process during termination.

Comment: ^ Only if those resources are owned by the process being terminated.  This is absolutely necessary, if for example, you're automating a hidden COM application (say, Word, or Excel) in the background, and you need to make sure to kill it before your app exits, etc.

Comment: this has a short looking answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555292/how-to-run-code-before-program-exit

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I am not sure where I found the code on the web, but I found it now in one of my old projects. This will allow you to do cleanup code in your console, e.g. when it is abruptly closed or due to a shutdown...

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
static EventHandler _handler;

enum CtrlType
{
  CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
  CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
  CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
  CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
  CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
}

private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
{
  switch (sig)
  {
      case CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT:
      case CtrlType.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
      case CtrlType.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
      case CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
      default:
          return false;
  }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Some biolerplate to react to close window event
  _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
  ...
}
```

**Update**

For those not checking the comments it seems that this particular solution does **not** work well (or at all) on **Windows 7**. The following [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/abf09824-4e4c-4f2c-ae1e-5981f06c9c6e) talks about this

Comment: Can you use this to cancel the exit? Other than for when it's shutting down!

Comment: james, I have no idea but the Handler signature returns a bool, so I'd try out what happens when you return true/false

Comment: This works great, only `bool Handler()` must `return false;` (it returns nothing in the code) so it would work. If it returns true, windows prompts "Terminate Process Now" dialog. =D

Comment: It looks like this solution does not work with Windows 7 for shutdown event, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/abf09824-4e4c-4f2c-ae1e-5981f06c9c6e

Comment: Be aware that if you put a breakpoint in the 'Handler' method it will throw a NullReferenceException. Checked in VS2010, Windows 7.

Comment: That's awesome, Charles, and shocking...looks like this answer is slowly expiring, and I can't quite see an alternative :/

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows 7 at all, Unless I converted it wrong to vb.net Although I wasn't ever able to properly translate the _handler part of it

Comment: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/545f1768-8038-4f7a-9177-060913d6872f/ and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createtoolhelp32snapshot

Comment: This worked great for me on Windows 7 (64-bit).  Not sure why everyone's saying it doesn't.  The only major modifications I made was to get rid of the enum and switch statement, and to "return false" from the method -- I do all my cleanup in the body of the method.

Comment: This code is not fired if you use End Process in Task Manager.

Comment: Tried it in Win7 using .NET 4.5, it does fire even if closed via Task Manager.

Comment: Possible source: [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/707e9ae1-a53f-4918-8ac4-62a1eddb3c4a/detecting-console-application-exit-in-c#fbfa88f1-588f-452c-883c-a3403ec1397f)

Comment: There's a very subtle gotcha that this code avoids.  You might look at this and think that the static _handler variable is not necessary, but it is.  If you delete this, the handler may get garbage collected (because the unmanaged code doesn't hold a reference to it).  If that happens, you'll get null reference exceptions when ctrl+C events are intercepted.

Comment: I am sorry but this code seems to work when pressing Ctrl+C, not when clicking 'X' button; in the latter case if I put a sleep in the first line of `Handler` method I am not able to get it completed because the console closes before, even with debugger attached and breakpoint set after 1 or 2 seconds the console closes {using Win10, .NET Framework 4.6.1}

Comment: works on Win11 and .NET Frame 4.8 also perfect ;) Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Full working example, works with ctrl-c, closing the windows with X and kill:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestTrapCtrlC {
    public class Program {
        static bool exitSystem = false;

        #region Trap application termination
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

        private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
        static EventHandler _handler;

        enum CtrlType {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
        }

        private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting system due to external CTRL-C, or process kill, or shutdown");

            //do your cleanup here
            Thread.Sleep(5000); //simulate some cleanup delay

            Console.WriteLine("Cleanup complete");

            //allow main to run off
            exitSystem = true;

            //shutdown right away so there are no lingering threads
            Environment.Exit(-1);

            return true;
        }
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Some boilerplate to react to close window event, CTRL-C, kill, etc
            _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);

            //start your multi threaded program here
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Start();

            //hold the console so it doesn’t run off the end
            while (!exitSystem) {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public void Start() {
            // start a thread and start doing some processing
            Console.WriteLine("Thread started, processing..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this on windows 7 with everything commented out of `Handler` except for the `return true` and a while loop to count seconds.  The application continues to run on ctrl-c but closes after 5 seconds when closing with the X.

Comment: I am sorry but using this code I am able to get *"Cleanup complete"* only if I press Ctrl+C, not if I close with 'X' button; in the latter case I get only *"Exiting system due to external CTRL-C, or process kill, or shutdown"* but then it seems the console closes before executing the remaining part of `Handler` method {using Win10, .NET Framework 4.6.1}

Comment: on windows 10 works for me CTRL-C, X on the window AND end process in Task Manager.

Comment: @JJ_Coder4Hire does it work for you if you select the root/parent console process in Task Manager and click `End Process`? For me it only works if I select the child console process (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710454/how-to-handle-end-task-from-task-manager-in-net-5-console-app) for more information).

Comment: Thank you. it works great for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 10):

Check also:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit
```

Comment: This only appears to catch exits from return or Environment.Exit, it does not catch CTRL+C, CTRL+Break, nor the actual close button on the console.

Comment: If you handle CTRL+C separately using `Console.CancelKeyPress` then `ProcessExit` event actually raised after all `CancelKeyPress` event handlers execution.

Comment: @Konard I couldn't get `ProcessExit` to work, even if I registered a handler for `CancelKeyPress`. Could it be that your handler for `CancelKeyPress` does the same as your `ProcessExit` handler, so it only seemed like `ProcessExit` got called?

Comment: @RobinHartmann I have retested that, and I got the same result - https://repl.it/@Konard/CultivatedForsakenQueryoptimizer These are two separate events and `ProcessExit` event is triggered after `CancelKeyPress` events.

Comment: @Konard Thanks for getting back to me, I also retested and this time I got `ProcessExit` to work, even without `CancelKeyPress`. What I mean by that is `ProcessExit` gets called when the console is closed using the close button, even if `CancelKeyPress` isn't registered. But you need `CancelKeyPress`, if you want to handle `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+Break`, because `ProcessExit` doesn't get called for those.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar problem, just my console App would be running in infinite loop with one preemptive statement on middle. Here is my solution:

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Init Code...
        Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;  // Register the function to cancel event

        // I do my stuffs

        while ( true )
        {
            // Code ....
            SomePreemptiveCall();  // The loop stucks here wating function to return
            // Code ...
        }
        return 0;  // Never comes here, but...
    }

    static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
        // Termitate what I have to terminate
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have the threads directly terminating the application? Perhaps it would be better to have a thread signal the main thread to say that the application should be terminated.

On receiving this signal, the main thread can cleanly shutdown the other threads and finally close itself down.

Comment: I have to agree with this answer. Forcing application exit and then trying to clean up afterward isn't he way to go. Control your application, Noit. Don't let it control you.

Comment: A thread spawned by me directly isn't necessarily the only thing that can close my application.  Ctrl-C and the "close button" are other ways that it can end.  The code posted by Frank, after minor modifications, fits perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

ZeroKelvin's answer works in Windows 10 x64, .NET 4.6 console app. For those who do not need to deal with the CtrlType enum, here is a really simple way to hook into the framework's shutdown:

```
class Program
{
    private delegate bool ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate(int sig);

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate handler, bool add);

    static ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate _consoleCtrlHandler;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _consoleCtrlHandler += s =>
        {
            //DoCustomShutdownStuff();
            return false;   
        };
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_consoleCtrlHandler, true);
    }
}
```

Returning FALSE from the handler tells the framework that we are not "handling" the control signal, and the next handler function in the list of handlers for this process is used. If none of the handlers returns TRUE, the default handler is called.

Note that when the user performs a logoff or shutdown, the callback is not called by Windows but is instead terminated immediately.

Answer (score 3):

There is for WinForms apps;

```
Application.ApplicationExit += CleanupBeforeExit;
```

For Console apps, try

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CleanupBeforeExit;
```

But I am not sure at what point that gets called or if it will work from within the current domain. I suspect not.

Comment: The help docs for DomainUnload say "The EventHandler delegate for this event can perform any termination activities before the application domain is unloaded." So it sounds like it does work within the current domain. However, it may not work for his need because his threads may keep the domain up.

Comment: This only handles CTRL+C and CTRL+Close, it doesn't catch exists via returning, Environment.Exit nor clicking the close button.

Comment: Doesn't catch CTRL + C for me with Mono on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 + Windows 10

- Allow for cleanup
- Single instance app
- Some goldplating

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        // if you want to allow only one instance otherwise remove the next line
        static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "YOURGUID-YOURGUID-YOURGUID-YO");

        static ManualResetEvent run = new ManualResetEvent(true);

        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);                
        private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
        static EventHandler exitHandler;
        enum CtrlType
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
        }
        private static bool ExitHandler(CtrlType sig)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting down: " + sig.ToString());            
            run.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return false; // If the function handles the control signal, it should return TRUE. If it returns FALSE, the next handler function in the list of handlers for this process is used (from MSDN).
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to allow only one instance otherwise remove the next 4 lines
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
            {
                return; // singleton application already started
            }

            exitHandler += new EventHandler(ExitHandler);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(exitHandler, true);

            try
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.SetBufferSize(Console.BufferWidth, 1024);

                Console.Title = "Your Console Title - XYZ";

                // start your threads here
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc1));
                thread1.Start();

                Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc2));
                thread2.IsBackground = true; // a background thread
                thread2.Start();

                while (run.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                // do thread syncs here signal them the end so they can clean up or use the manual reset event in them or abort them
                thread1.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("fail: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
            finally
            {                
                // do app cleanup here

                // if you want to allow only one instance otherwise remove the next line
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();

                // remove this after testing
                Console.Beep(5000, 100);
            }
        }

        public static void ThreadFunc1()
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line == "command 1")
                {

                }
                else if (line == "command 1")
                {

                }
                else if (line == "?")
                {

                }

                Console.Write("> ");
            }
        }


        public static void ThreadFunc2()
        {
            while (run.WaitOne(0))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

           // do thread cleanup here
            Console.Beep();         
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that this seems to be the most robust answer. However, be careful about changing your console buffer size: if the buffer height is less than the window height, the program will throw an exception on startup.

Answer (score 1):

The [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/abf09824-4e4c-4f2c-ae1e-5981f06c9c6e) mentioned above by Charle B in comment to flq

Deep down says:

> SetConsoleCtrlHandler won't work on windows7 if you link to user32

Some where else in the thread it is suggested to crate a hidden window. So I create a winform and in onload I attached to console and execute original Main.
And then SetConsoleCtrlHandle works fine (SetConsoleCtrlHandle is called as suggested by flq)

```
public partial class App3DummyForm : Form
{
    private readonly string[] _args;

    public App3DummyForm(string[] args)
    {
        _args = args;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void App3DummyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        App3.Program.OriginalMain(_args);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();
}
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. I have multi-window WFP app and I use console (`AllocConsole` as in your example) to show some additional information. The problem is that the whole app (all Windows) get closed if user clicks on the (X) on Console Window. The `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` works, but the app halts anyway before any code in the handler executed (I see breakpoints fired and right then the app halts).

Comment: But I found solution which works for me -- I simple **DISABLED** close button. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052992/how-can-i-disable-close-button-of-console-window-in-a-visual-studio-console-appl

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in VB.net. (I searched the internet and couldn't find an equivalent for it) Here it is translated into vb.net.

```
    <DllImport("kernel32")> _
    Private Function SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ByVal HandlerRoutine As HandlerDelegate, ByVal Add As Boolean) As Boolean
    End Function
    Private _handler As HandlerDelegate
    Private Delegate Function HandlerDelegate(ByVal dwControlType As ControlEventType) As Boolean
    Private Function ControlHandler(ByVal controlEvent As ControlEventType) As Boolean
        Select Case controlEvent
            Case ControlEventType.CtrlCEvent, ControlEventType.CtrlCloseEvent
                Console.WriteLine("Closing...")
                Return True
            Case ControlEventType.CtrlLogoffEvent, ControlEventType.CtrlBreakEvent, ControlEventType.CtrlShutdownEvent
                Console.WriteLine("Shutdown Detected")
                Return False
        End Select
    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Try
            _handler = New HandlerDelegate(AddressOf ControlHandler)
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, True)
     .....
End Sub
```

Comment: Above solution does not work for me vb.net 4.5 framework ControlEventType is not getting resolved. I was able to use this idea as solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317082/how-to-close-console-application-gracefully-on-windows-shutdown