# .NET console application exit event

Tags: .net, console-application, complexity-theory

In .NET, is there a method, such as an event, for detecting when a console application is exiting? I need to clean up some threads and [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) objects.

I am running a message loop, without a form, from the console application.  A [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) component that I am using seems to require that the application pump messages.

I have tried adding a handler to Process.GetCurrentProcess.Exited and Process.GetCurrentProcess.Disposed.

I have also tried adding a handler to *Application.ApplicationExit* and *Application.ThreadExit* events, but they are not firing.  Perhaps that is because I am not using a form.

Comment: The Process.GetCurrentProcess().Exited event should fire if you first set Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; otherwise, it won't fire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture console exit C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp)

Comment: @Triynko how is that? Process.Exited is fired after the process is exited. And if the own application is exited then there is no code executed at all. Pretty useless imo..

Comment: Complete working example near the end of this post in C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646827/on-exit-for-a-console-application

Answer (score 116):

You can use the [`ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event of the [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);           
        // do some work

    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is a full example program with an empty "message pump" running on a separate thread, that allows the user to input a quit command in the console to close down the application gracefully. After the loop in MessagePump you will probably want to clean up resources used by the thread in a nice manner. It's better to do that there than in ProcessExit for several reasons:

- Avoid cross-threading problems; if external COM objects were created on the MessagePump thread, it's easier to deal with them there.
- There is a time limit on ProcessExit (3 seconds by default), so if cleaning up is time consuming, it may fail if pefromed within that event handler.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    private static bool _quitRequested = false;
    private static object _syncLock = new object();
    private static AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        // start the message pumping thread
        Thread msgThread = new Thread(MessagePump);
        msgThread.Start();
        // read input to detect "quit" command
        string command = string.Empty;
        do
        {
            command = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (!command.Equals("quit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        // signal that we want to quit
        SetQuitRequested();
        // wait until the message pump says it's done
        _waitHandle.WaitOne();
        // perform any additional cleanup, logging or whatever
    }

    private static void SetQuitRequested()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            _quitRequested = true;
        }
    }

    private static void MessagePump()
    {
        do
        {
            // act on messages
        } while (!_quitRequested);
        _waitHandle.Set();
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Fredrik.  This event does not appear to fire either.

Comment: How does your process exit? Do you call any code that makes it exit?

Comment: Currently the only way to exit, is the to click the Close button on the console window or perhaps press ctrl+c.

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense; you are not exiting the application, you are killing it with brute force. There is no event that will pick that up. You need to implement a way of gracefully quitting your application.

Comment: Are you serious? Surely when any Windows.Forms application is closed by a user closing the main form you have a chance to perform some cleanup! I am implementing a batch and it's completely unacceptable to just have the process die on me with no chance to even log the fact that the the job was aborted...

Comment: The corresponding use of ProcessExit() for VB.NET is in *[Closing function in a VB.NET console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099377)*.

Comment: This does not work. pasted it into a new console project, resolved the dependencies, put a break point on CurrentDomain_ProcessExit and it does not fire when CTRL-C is pushed, or when the X on the window is clicked. See my complete working response below

Comment: @TheDag This isn't a problem of .NET. In Windows Vista, the console application has been changed, so that instead of getting a message when the user clicks the close button, the process is basically killed. Ctrl-C *can* be intercepted, though - using the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event.

Comment: This neglects many termination scenarios. JJ_Coder4Hire's solution handles everything.

Comment: In what context does it not work, @Switch? To the best of my recollection, it worked well on the .NET framework that was current when I posted this, 11 years ago.

Comment: It never fires the event CurrentDomain_ProcessExit.  The one JJ_Coder4Hire posted below works perfectly.

Answer (score 63):

Here is a complete, very simple .NET solution that works in all versions of Windows. Simply paste it into a new project, run it and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to view how it handles it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestTrapCtrlC{
    public class Program{
        static bool exitSystem = false;

        #region Trap application termination
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

        private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
        static EventHandler _handler;

        enum CtrlType {
         CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
         CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
         CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
         CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
         CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
         }

        private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting system due to external CTRL-C, or process kill, or shutdown");

            //do your cleanup here
            Thread.Sleep(5000); //simulate some cleanup delay

            Console.WriteLine("Cleanup complete");

            //allow main to run off
             exitSystem = true;

            //shutdown right away so there are no lingering threads
            Environment.Exit(-1);

            return true;
        }
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Some biolerplate to react to close window event, CTRL-C, kill, etc
            _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);

            //start your multi threaded program here
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Start();

            //hold the console so it doesn’t run off the end
            while(!exitSystem) {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public void Start() {
            // start a thread and start doing some processing
            Console.WriteLine("Thread started, processing..");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This seems to be the best C# solution that works for all exit scenarios!
Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: the code dosen't works in windows xp sp3. if we close the application from task manager.

Comment: Will this code work on Linux in a .NET Core console application ?  I didn't try but "Kernel32" seems not portable to me...

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly for me. I'm usually in Java land but at a client site I've had to write a multi-threaded C# console app, and I don't know C# quite as well, that connects to a realtime market data feed API. I need to make sure I clean stuff up, set some other server stuff etc. This is a good solution for me.

Comment: I used this successfully. However, I used a ManualResetEvent to signal when to begin shutting down. (And another ManualResetEvent waited on in Handler to signal when the shut down finished.)

Comment: In the case user click on console close button Thread.Sleep(5000000) not working and console will close after wait for 5 sec. So this code is not completely work.

Comment: This doesn't work If I run the application from Visual Studio and stop the app from VS. Is there any way to handle that case?

Comment: This does catch close and ctrl+C, but not "process kill", despite what the comment says, at least not for me, eg when kill the console task/process from Windows' task manager.
I'm not sure it's even possible, from what I read elsewhere the only way to detect rude kills would be from _another_ process.

Answer (score 22):

The application is a server which simply runs until the system shuts down or it receives a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or the console window is closed.

Due to the extraordinary nature of the application, it is not feasible to "gracefully" exit.  (It may be that I could code another application which would send a "server shutdown" message, but that would be overkill for one application and still insufficient for certain circumstances like when the server (actually the operating system) is actually shutting down.)

Because of these circumstances I added a "[ConsoleCtrlHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler)" where I stop my threads and clean up my COM objects, etc...

```
Public Declare Auto Function SetConsoleCtrlHandler Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handler As HandlerRoutine, ByVal Add As Boolean) As Boolean

Public Delegate Function HandlerRoutine(ByVal CtrlType As CtrlTypes) As Boolean

Public Enum CtrlTypes
  CTRL_C_EVENT = 0
  CTRL_BREAK_EVENT
  CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT
  CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5
  CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
End Enum

Public Function ControlHandler(ByVal ctrlType As CtrlTypes) As Boolean
.
.clean up code here
.
End Function

Public Sub Main()
.
.
.
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(New HandlerRoutine(AddressOf ControlHandler), True)
.
.
End Sub
```

This setup seems to work out perfectly.  Here is [a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810221940/http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx) to some C# code for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me  :)  +1  You should mark your own answer as THE answer.

Comment: There seems to be a 3 second limit for the handler to finish. If you don't finish in time, you will be ungracefully terminated. That includes if you are sitting on a breakpoint in the debugger!

Comment: This works but a complete working sample is found below in C#

Comment: This code is not fired if you use End Process in Task Manager.

Comment: @dan-gph The program terminates when the main thread finishes. Add something like

       //hold the console so it doesn’t run off the end

            while(!exitSystem) {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

Comment: ControlHandler will terminate after 5 sec, Even when clean up code not finished yet.

Answer (score 11):

For the CTRL+C case, you can use this:

```
// Tell the system console to handle CTRL+C by calling our method that
// gracefully shuts down.
Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);


static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
            // Cleanup here
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
}
```

Comment: Does this handle shutdown logoff ctrl+c etc...?

Comment: Tried it, the event never fires.  Same as the other events.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a console application and you are pumping messages, you may be able use the WM_QUIT message.

Comment: I wonder about that too. I suppose it *could* be the case that windows doesn't send the message to a console app, but it seems weird to me. One should think the requirement would be to have a message pump, not whether or not it has a GUI...

Answer (score 0):

Minimal version based on @user79755 solution :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestConsoleApp {
    internal class Program {
        private static bool notStoped = true;

        private delegate bool CloseEventHandler(int sig);

        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CloseEventHandler handler, bool add);

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(Handler, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Don't press Enter...");
            Console.WriteLine("Just close the app");
            while (Console.ReadLine() != null);
            //wait for terminate
            do {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            } while(notStoped);
        }

        protected static bool Handler(int sig) {
            Console.WriteLine("It's closing now");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Almost done");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            notStoped = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```