# How to track pc start up, shutdown and critical shutdown

Tags: c#, windows

I have approximately 250 laptops on mobile carts that I know are not being fully utilized. I am writing a program that writes a log file to capture the power on, and shut down events.  However, when I try to trap the immediate shutdown event (user holds the power button in) I don't get data written to the text file.

Any input would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

    namespace Log
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            string CrLf = System.Environment.NewLine;
            private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
            private static int WM_ENDSESSION_CRITICAL = 0x40000000;

            private static bool systemShutdown = false;

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Write_Data("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + "Power on");            
            }


            protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {

                if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
                {
                    Write_Data("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + "Power off");
                    systemShutdown = true;
                }
                // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
                // raised in the base WndProc.

                    if (m.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION_CRITICAL)
                    {
                        Write_Data("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + "Critical power down");
                        systemShutdown = true;
                    }

                    base.WndProc(ref m);
            }       

            private void Write_Data(string str_Data)
            {
                using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("../Log.txt", true))
                {
                    output.WriteLine(str_Data);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might make more sense to read the system's EventLog  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx and just find when these events happened

Or if that's not ideal, instead of listening for the shutdown event, hook in to the program's termination and just assume if the program is closing, the computer is being shut down, and call your Write_Data in there.  Note that some of the solutions in this SO thread ["On Exit" for a Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646827/on-exit-for-a-console-application)   don't work on Windows7, and act different in Console/Form application shutdown