# Console Application: Closing Window vs End of Program

Tags: c#, com, console-application

I'm writing a small library to help manage some objects in Excel.  I'm testing this DLL using a simple console application that makes calls to the library, then prints the results out.  I can then end the program in any of the typical fashions, usually by either hitting return (thus completing the `ReadLine` call) or hitting the window's close button.  **However, the reference to the Excel instance behaves differently based on how the program exits.**

In my program, if no existing reference to Excel can be found, I use the following line:

```
_app = new ExcelInterop.Application();
```

where `_app` is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` in either a static or singleton class (I've tried both, both have the same results).

Assuming the program creates it's own instance (and doesn't find one already open):

- *The instance will remain open* if the program is exited by clicking the close window button:
- *The instance is released, and no longer appears in the task manager* if the program is exited by reaching the end of the code in the `Main` block

**Is there anyway to make all program ends behave like the latter case?**  Furthermore, this DLL will go on to be used in a WPF application, **are there similar concerns in WPF?**  Or at large, even?

Perhaps most importantly, *what are the technical reasons for this behavior?*

Comment: maybe do your tidy up on an close event like in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp

Comment: @jgok222 That seems like a pretty good conclusion, but do you have any idea what exactly is happening here under the hood?  The most confusing part is that I haven't written any clean-up code at all at this point.  I was fully expecting the instance to remain open in all cases.  I guess I feel a little uneasy pushing code that I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A console mode program is a pretty hostile place for the COM interop wrapper objects that are needed for an apartment-threaded out-of-process COM server.  This program demonstrates the issue:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var prg = new Program();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    ~Program() {
        Console.WriteLine("Clean-up completed");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
    }
}
```

Try it both ways, by pressing Enter and by clicking the Close button.  You'll see that the finalizer never gets executed.  The operating system terminates the process before it gets a chance to shut down properly when you click the Close button.

Same problem with the finalizers for the COM wrappers.  They cannot execute so IUnknown::Release() doesn't get called and the Office program is completely unaware that the client program is no longer there.  Windows has its own cleanup for abandoned out-of-process servers but that doesn't work for Office programs for some otherwise mysterious reason.

That explains it, fixing it isn't so easy.  You'll have to [register a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647168/17034) that runs when the Close button is clicked.  If necessary, set the *app* reference to null if it is still in scope and force the finalizer to run with GC.Collect() + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers().  Do keep in mind that this is just a band-aid, not a fix.  It won't work when the user aborts your program while you are busy talking to the Office program.  Avoiding a console mode project is best.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Is the close button case unique to console applications?  Is this something I'd have to worry about in WPF?  The application this will be a part of makes good use of WPF's close events.

Comment: GUI apps don't have this problem.

Comment: Awesome, in that case I think I'll make a public cleanup method, and let any console developers (which I doubt there'll ever be any of) handle the event listeners for their own program.

Comment: @SandyGifford The standard for the "public cleanup method" is implementing the `IDisposeable` interface and putting your cleanup code in there. Then users of your class can put the instance of your wrapper either in their own `using` statement or make their class `IDisposeable` too and dispose of it there.