# How to Close FiddlerCore when windows is Shutting Down

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I would Like to Close The Fiddler When windows is Shutting Down  Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown(), I have no idea how to do this if some one can help me out it would be really Great.

What My application Does is It Uses the Fiddlercore and Intercept the traffic 
and it works Good But when the Application is not Closed Properly or if the Operating restarts its the Internet wont work because the FiddlerApplications is not Shutdown Properly.

Note : this is not a Winform Application its a Console Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get an event raised when the console application closes and from that event handler you can properly dispose the Fiddler application.

One possible solution can be found here:
["On Exit" for a Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646827/on-exit-for-a-console-application)