# Threading in VB.Net Console Application

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, console

I have a console application that is built in VB.Net. Now I have a timer in that application. All I want to do is at a particyualr time i will call another exe (which is built in VB 6.0) and again get the control back to this console application.
 Now what is happening is that I am being able to call the second exe from the console application , but then the control is not returning back to the same console application.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: How are you calling the EXE? Does your EXE actually exit? Is it running in the background still? Can you provide us with the code that's calling the EXE?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start(myProgramPathAndFileName)
```

This should create a new process and return control to your console app.

You can do more with this process by storing the return value:

```
MyProcess = Process.Start(myProgramPathAndFilename)
```

Then call this when your application exits

```
MyProcess.Kill
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx for more info on processes.

See: [.NET Console Application Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event) for information on handling Application Exit as an event.

Comment: @@Ken:: Your post seems to work ok, but when the console application is closed , can we close the other EXE without changing any code in the other EXE.??

Comment: Yes.  Grab the process id.  Kill it on application exit.

Comment: I have the process ID , I know how to kill it. But I am confused where to write this code. I have implemented a logic by which my console app will not close untill and unless i write 'EXIT'. the code is given below:

Comment: While console.readline.trim.toupper<>"EXIT")              console.writeline  ("")                                          end while

Comment: I think that might be another question in itsself - fortunately there's a lot of resources on this site.  Someone else wanted to trap the application exit of a console app in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event  You should do something similar and kill the process within that event.