# C# - Is it possible to catch a <Process>.Exited event fired from the main process?

Tags: c#, events, process

I am writing a C# console application and am trying to check when my main program's process has exited, so that I can do some cleanup before exiting, but the event never seems to fire. Here is the code to set the event handler:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
CloseConsoleHandler close = new CloseConsoleHandler(test);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += close.CloseHandler; 
//I also tried process.Exited += new EventHandler(close.CloseHandler);
```

It just never seems to fire, not when the program ends naturally, not when I click the close button... never. Is this even possible?

Comment: You should try to do your cleanup deterministically, as soon as you're finished with whatever you're cleaning up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Process **exited** event should logically fire AFTER a process exits, so therefore it's impossible to catch it's own exit.

But there are other alternatives, like implementing Dispose in your class to do cleanup, or for some reason you need the Process exited event, just monitor the process from another process.

Comment: I have tried implementing Dispose() and a destructor, but neither is called.

Comment: call Dispose explicitly BEFORE exiting, just for example, if you have a database connection, you'd call the dispose of the settings class that communicates with the database BEFORE you dispose the DB connection.

Comment: But I want this to be called when the console window is closed by clicking the close button, or when the user presses CTRL+C. I have no idea how to detect when this has happened.

Comment: Maybe a similar question's this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event/1120033#1120033 may help..

Answer (score 9):

That won't work; once the process has ended, your code is *gone*.

Handle the [`AppDomain.ProcessExit` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx).

Comment: I tried both. I have now tried implementing a destructor and a dispose method in the appropriate class, but they're never called either. It's so annoying because all I want to do is kill an .exe if it is still open when the program closes.

Comment: I think that we need to create a second application in order to monitor processes and keep alive the one you want by detecting it has been killed and running it again

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom handler to the ProcessExit event and do your cleanup there. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Register hanlder to ProcessExit event
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += ProcessExitHanlder;
    }

    private static void ProcessExitHanlder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cleanup!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a description of the proposed solution, not just some lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Process.Exit is called only for associated processes and after termination.
Try using ProcessExit event of current AppDomain.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to solve that at application level if you own the main app too (it sounds like): signal the child process from the main app with some technique when the main app is closing. Maybe I'd try to signal synchronously this time, so the main app leaves time for the child for cleanup. This approach has it's own drawbacks though. The ideal would be to catch some system event at your child process.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two ways - depending on your preference one P/Invoke way (see http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.clr/2003-11/msg00214.html )... this calls a delegate you define in a separate thread upon Exit of your app and works with console...

The other way is `AppDomain.ProcessExit` - which has a time limit it is allowed to run (default 3 seconds).