# Running "termination" code on application close

Tags: c#

I have a program that simply runs another program and monitors it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Process exeProc = Process.Start(getStartInfo()))
    {
        while (!exeProc.HasExited)
        {
            // does some stuff while the monitored program is still running
        }
    }

    // 
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

When the other program exits, so does mine.

I would like the opposite to be true as well: how do I make it so that closing my program will also terminate the process that I'm monitoring?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646827/on-exit-for-a-console-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already another question which links to a question on msdn that has a working answer (I know too much indirection). [C# how to receive system close or exit events in a commandline application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621287/c-sharp-how-to-receive-system-close-or-exit-events-in-a-commandline-application)

I'll post the code here since it is preferred, just want to give credit where it is due since I am taking this snippet verbatim.

```
namespace Detect_Console_Application_Exit2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool isclosing = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);

            Console.WriteLine("CTRL+C,CTRL+BREAK or suppress the application to exit");
            while (!isclosing) ;

        }

        private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
        {
            // Put your own handler here
            switch (ctrlType)
            {
                case CtrlTypes.CTRL_C_EVENT:
                    isclosing = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("CTRL+C received!");
                    break;

                case CtrlTypes.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
                    isclosing = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("CTRL+BREAK received!");
                    break;

                case CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                    isclosing = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Program being closed!");
                    break;

                case CtrlTypes.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
                case CtrlTypes.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
                    isclosing = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("User is logging off!");
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }



        #region unmanaged
        // Declare the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function
        // as external and receiving a delegate.

        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

        // A delegate type to be used as the handler routine
        // for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
        public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

        // An enumerated type for the control messages
        // sent to the handler routine.
        public enum CtrlTypes
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I can easily define different behavior for all sorts of events as well. That's pretty nice!

Comment: +1... also could simply dup as well since that question have almost the same code in one of the answers...