# Stop Debugging Event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

How or where can I run a command when the application closes, even if is a debug stop?

I need to perform a command in any exit, even if the user is a developer and click on "stop debugging" button on Visual Studio.

I try with

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm wrong or is not the event.

I'm using Winforms and not, on Form Close can't be the event.

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 Net Framework 2.0 (by client requirement), but is just for information.

Maybe can I rewrite this?:

```
public static void Exit();
```

Comment: I'm curious - why would the client be bothered about debug being stopped?

Comment: @m.edmondson I was looking at doing this for some web testing - it needs to fire up browsers during tests and exiting the debugger doesnt run the rest of a using block that cleans up.  This is a bit annoying as you end up with lots of browsers being open

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is the "stop debugging" function will halt the application entirely - so **no more** code within that application will run.

Your only way of achieving this would be to watch the process being debugged externally and execute the code if it has been halted.

According to [MSDN]:

> Stop Debugging terminates the process you are debugging if the program
>   was launched from Visual Studio.

However you may be able to achieve what you want with a [visual studio add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968855.aspx).

Comment: I understand. +1 for the workaround. Do you have any link to read about that can be done in the app itself, to include it on the TD/FD app documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not as I've never done anything like this before - perhaps another answer will come along.

Comment: What does it mean to "halt the application entirely"? Sending WM_CLOSE to the main form? Or calling TerminateProcess? You suggest the latter is what happens, but do you have any evidence to support this claim?

Comment: I have no evidence either way - perhaps you could improve my answer?

Comment: @m.edmondson Unfortunately not... I'm just also curious about what the "stop debugging" button does :)

Comment: @kol - I've done a quick google and added to my answer - looks like it terminates the process

Comment: it seems to be the final answer. But I keep the workaround, is not a bad idea for all.

Comment: @Leandro - I've updated my answer, you may be able to achieve this with an add-in

Comment: Yep I want to try if Process_Exit works but I can't get solve it. I need to call a control and not a messagebox

Comment: Process_Exit doesn't work.  It's event handler doesn't run either.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
// Handle the ApplicationExit event to know when the application is exiting.
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
// When the application is exiting
}
```

Is this what you implemented?

Comment: I don't think this will execute when halting the debug?

Comment: Yep, that was I tried. But it doesnt work (works only with the normal flow of the app).

Comment: Oops, I miss-read the question. He wants it to run even if the program is stopped by a debug point by a developer. I do not believe it will execute when using debug.

Comment: np, your comment helps me on my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use  use **Suspend** and **Resume layout.** Also, if you have a combo box filled with stuff, it can slow you down. I would also consider going under "**Solution Explorer**" and right click and select "**Properties**" at the bottom. Choose "**Configuration Properties**" and select "Release" verse "Debugging." This will greatly improve form loading time.
[This link will explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please avoid use links to answer in S.O. Please read the guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prueba {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            //This is the magic line code :P
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }
    }
}
```

The reference is here (Fredrik Mörk): [.NET Console Application Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event)

Comment: How can I call from CurrentDomain_ProcessExit a control on my Form1 ?

Comment: Want to launch a form from this event?

Comment: I need to change a lot of things, and one of them is a dispose of an object (notifyicon) on Form1 (created by designer)

Comment: If you need change any propertie of an object before to luch a form, in the constructor of the form, after of the method InitializeComponents(), you can write the necesary code for changing the properties of the objects. Explain me more what you do.

Comment: dispose the notifyicon or run a public void that dispose it when the app stops (also close a stream, etc etc etc). Clean up the solution and the build

Comment: Personally I think you should not close streams or dispose objects at this level of the program, each object must be dispose, in this case, to close the form ... but if you need to do this, you have to declare a static class and declare static variables (globals at application), if you need to force the release or closing streams, then put the code in that method. (Sorry my english, i can't speak english)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me.  I am trying from a console app.

Comment: This absolutely does not work.  The Process_Exit handler is not called when I press the stop debugging button.