# Detecting or disabling (if possible) console application exit manually

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm working on a console application that tries to download some files from a website by logging in and then copying the files to a shared folder.

Since its very much possible that the user might click on close button manually or tries to end the process manually somehow, is there a way I can detect this?

Comment: Why a console application? Do you want to run the app on a schedule? In that case you can create a scheduled task that doesn't open a window.

Comment: You can intercept this via a Win32 call. Unfortunately, I cannot find where I saw I thought I saw it. :(

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1119841/15541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty project instead. So you will have a "hidden process", with no UI which a user will try to close.

Comment: this is an idea but it will consume and allocate unnecessary resources, this is a job for a windows service, do you agree?

Comment: @Freeman: I think it depends on several factors: how does start the process: should it start on OS boot, or by user or another app manually? how often should it run: once or periodically?

Comment: yes but the start time was not the point, even the number of loaded assemblies is bigger on a windows form project then in a service project as the last one does not need the the GUI libraries loaded to memory.

Comment: @Freeman: If you don't create a form, you don't need to load these assemblies, you even can remove it from references. ProjectType=Windows just directs Windows do not create a console for this process.

Comment: I don't want to comment this further without a reason, but if you want a project that does not require some assemblies why not just make one, instead of making a project with more assemblies and the manually removing its references?

Comment: @Freeman: You're right, you can create just an empty project.

Comment: Even better i can create a project that suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

It rather recommended that you make this a windows service application so it will run as a service that implies no user interaction at all with the application.