# How to close XML tag if in while loop and then the the user closes the console application

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a Xml file, however I have a while loop that asks the user to insert some data. The problem I am having is that when the user closes the command prompt box ( to input the data) the root node doesn't close itself.

How can I close the root node "People" when the user exits?

thanks

** I am using c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

namespace XML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Users\\gghossei\\Desktop\\XmlTestDoc.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            // root
            writer.WriteStartElement("People");
            writer.Flush();
            bool done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                string message;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your message:");
                message = Console.ReadLine();
                writer.WriteElementString("Something", message);
                writer.Flush();

            }
writer.WriteEndElement();


        }
    }
```

the problem is when you close this while loop by pressing x on the command prompt it doesn't close the root node "People"...

Comment: What language are you using?  C#? VB.NET? Java?  Something else?

Comment: Hi tim i am using c#

Comment: Please tag you question properly, and include the code.

Comment: You don't include your full code, so it's not clear exactly what your problem is.  Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem, ideally as a console application, that we could copy and debug.  (For instance, where are you calling `XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()` for the root element?)

Comment: I am after the while loop, however if you exit the command prompt how will it close the root?

Comment: Here I gave you a similar example..

Comment: That is terminating your app.  YOu would either have to write a handler to trap that, or let the user enter a special keyword to indicate "end of my entry".

Comment: There's not function that would trap that it's closing?

Comment: Possibly see [.NET Console Application Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event).

Comment: I'm not figuring this out.. it's not letting me.. there is no other way?