# C# Close Process and run Code on Process

Tags: c#, process, exit

I'd like to Run Code on Application Exit. My Problem is that I have two Application. The First is running. My Second Application now is going to Close the First Application. But on Closing I'd like to run code in the First Application.

```
public class First
{
   public static Main(string[] args)
   {
        Console.ReadLine();
   }

  public void DoSomethingOnExit()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("It Works");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}


public class Second
{
    public void method(int number)
    {
        var prozess = Process.GetProcessById(number);
        prozess.Close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could use a named-pipe or some other kind of inter-process communication.

Comment: Is it a console app? If so then it's a duplicate of [.NET Console Application Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event)

Comment: This should be split into 2 questions, One about executing a method on application exit and one on communication between 2 apps. One showing lack of research and the other about using SO as code service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Running");            
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }



 [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

    private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
    static EventHandler _handler;

    enum CtrlType
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
    }

    private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
    {
        switch (sig)
        {
            case CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                DoSomeShutdownStuff();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```