# How to show message box on .net core Console application?

Tags: .net-core, console-application, messagebox

I'm developing .net core console application. I want to alert to user when want to exit application. Like below;

```
 MessageBox.Show("Contiue or not", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.No)
    Application.Exit();
```

But I can't add System.Windows.Forms referance to the my project. I'm getting this error.

```
 Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Is that possible to show Message Box on .net core Console Application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event           maybe this helps

Comment: Per the [porting instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/porting/winforms), changing the SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` and adding `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` will make this work. (The output type has to be left to `Exe` if you want a console application.) Note that it remains inherently a bad idea to do GUI calls from a console app, of course, even ignoring the gratuitous added platform incompatibility (this only works on Windows).

Answer (score 4):

In order to use Windows Forms you need to modify `.csproj`:

- set `UseWindowsForms` to `true`
- append `-windows` to `TargetFramework` (e.g. `net6.0-windows`)

`ConsoleApp.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, Console!");
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, Popup!");
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Notes:

- I checked this solution on .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 and .NET 6 on Windows x64.
- If you **don't** want console window to be shown, set `OutputType` in `.csproj` to `WinExe` instead of `Exe`.
- Windows Forms works only on Windows, so as this solution.
- On .NET Core 3.1 there is no requirement to change target framework to Windows, however it is still impossible to publish executable for Linux OS.
- If you need cross-platform solution that shows popups on Windows and only use console on Linux – you can create custom build configuration and use preprocessor directives as in the example below.

Cross-platform `ConsoleApp.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;WindowsDebug;WindowsRelease</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'WindowsDebug' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'WindowsRelease'">
    <DefineConstants>WindowsRuntime</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Cross-platform `Program.cs`

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, Console!");

#if WindowsRuntime
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, Popup!");
#endif
```

Comment: Can this application be run on Linux (without the Windows dialog then)?

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht, no, when project uses Windows Forms it can only target Windows. However, you can create custom build configuration and use preprocessor directives. I added a code example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some console apps need this line added to the project as well...

```
<DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
```

Adding this to the example in Daniil's post would give you this...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>

    <!--Insert DisableWinExeOutputInference here -->
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>

  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How to understand, when to use it? What the parameter does?