# How can I detect if a user clicks the "X" Button in the top right corner of a Console Application (C# .net)

Tags: c#, console-application

I know in a WinForm application I can use the "FormClosing" Event Handler. Is it possible to do something like that in a Console application? Im using the .Net Framework

Comment: Not as far as I know. Why do you need to?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119841/12888024

Comment: You can, but it's not straightforward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp

Comment: Would it NEED to be because of the "X" button?

Comment: I need to do this because I am trying to add events when they close the application such as a dialog saying "Are you sure you would like to close the application", something like that.

Comment: @JordanHouston if you're showing a dialog for a console application, perhaps you should be using another type of application.

Comment: The requirements say a "Command Line Application"