# how to automatically exit the application in c# when computer shutdowns?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Sharp Windows Application prevents Windows from shutting down / logging off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498432/c-sharp-sharp-windows-application-prevents-windows-from-shutting-down-logging)

I want to write code for automatically exit from my application when user shutdowns the computer. I have done the project in C# developer.
Now I can't shutdown the computer without manually exiting the application.
Please advice.

Comment: Shutting down your computer should end all running programs?

Answer (score 1):

You may use SystemEvents class described in below link :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx

Subscribe to SessionEnded event which triggers when User logs off or shut down system.

you may write a code in this event to terminate the application by itself.
for eg. Application.Exit() closes the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx). Just subscribe to [SessionEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx) and perform any closing operation you want for your application.

**Word of Caution** : I think you wont get enough time there to perform any complex task. But since you just want to exit from your application, just call `Application.Exit()` in the event handler.