# How to handle "End Task" from Task Manager in .NET 5 console app?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, console, exit

My .NET 5 console application registers a [HandlerRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) by using [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler), so it can do some cleanup before exiting.
This allows me to react to `CTRL+C`/`CTRL+BREAK`, `ALT+F4` and the console being closed using the `X` button.
Sadly, the HandlerRoutine doesn't get called when Task Manager tries to terminate the application after clicking `End Task` in the **`Process`** tab, even though the [documentation for HandlerRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine#parameters) states the following regarding `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`:

> A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console (either by clicking Close on the console window's window menu, or **by clicking the End Task button command from Task Manager**).

Am I missing something or is the documentation wrong in this case? And is there another way to handle `End Task`?
I also tried the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit) event, but it behaves in the same way.

Regarding the `End Task` button in the **`Details`** tab of Task Manager: that one definitely can't be handled, as far as I understand, because it terminates the process immediately.

Below you can find a MWE to reproduce the problem. I'm running it on Windows 10 version 20H2.

```cs
// requires NuGet package: System.Windows.Extensions
using System.Media;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GracefulTermination.ConsoleDotNet5
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly TaskCompletionSource terminationTcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
        private static readonly HandlerRoutine handlerRoutine = HandleConsoleCtrl;

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlType dwCtrlType);

        private enum CtrlType : uint
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
        }

        static async Task Main()
        {
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handlerRoutine, add: true);

            await terminationTcs.Task;
        }

        // FIXME not called when using "End Task" in "Process" tab of Task Manager
        private static bool HandleConsoleCtrl(CtrlType dwCtrlType)
        {
            SystemSound sound = dwCtrlType == CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT
                ? SystemSounds.Hand
                : SystemSounds.Asterisk;

            sound.Play();
            terminationTcs.SetResult();

            return false;
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(
            HandlerRoutine handler,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            bool add
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I did some more experimenting and it turns out this behavior changes depending on which exact process "End Task" is invoked on.

[image]

The picture above shows the process structure when running my application in `PowerShell`, but `cmd.exe` behaves in the same way.
Processes, which **do not** call the HandlerRoutine upon clicking "End Task" are marked in
 red and the ones that **do** call it are marked in
 green.
`Host für Konsolenfenster` is `conhost.exe`, which I did not attempt to terminate.
I also should add that ending the processes marked in  red randomly **does** trigger the handler for one try at a time, but this is very rare.
For me, handling the termination of the parent process (`Windows PowerShell (3)`) is the biggest concern, because it's the one most likely to be selected by the user.
But I would like to be able to handle all cases, if possible.

**EDIT 2**

The [documentation for SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler#remarks) also states the following:

> The system generates CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT signals when the user closes the console, logs off, or shuts down the system so that the process has an **opportunity to clean up** before termination. **Console functions, or any C run-time functions that call console functions**, may not work reliably during processing of any of the three signals mentioned previously.

Therefore, I replaced `Console.Beep()` in the example with `SystemSound.Play()`, so there are no console functions being used during cleanup.

**EDIT 3**

The marshaling doesn't seem to be the issue, because `HandleConsoleCtrl()` is being called and even receives `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` when the console is closed using the `X` button.
It just doesn't work when using `End Task`.
Nevertheless, I did improve the marshaling as recommended by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

Comment: Are you invoking `End Task` on the process of your particular app directly, or on the process of the console itself? `End Task` is a brute force termination for most processes. Perhaps Task Manager treats a console window process special, that is why the console can receive a signal when terminating the console, but not when terminating a process inside the console.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point! If I invoke it on the parent console process as shown in Task Manager or on my app directly, it won't work like 95 % of the time. But if I invoke it on the console process, which is shown as a sibling to my app, it DOES work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the question.

Comment: In order to receive `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` you need to terminate the process created the console window instead of terminate child process associate with this parent process. Terminate process group from task manager will not cause `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` sent. This seems by design. And it is not suggested to depend on `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` for doing clean up because [some or all of the internal console cleanup routines may have been called before executing the process signal handler.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler#remarks)

Comment: Terminating process from task manager is considered an "exception" case. You can record except exiting and do some recovery stuff if you want to keep state consistant etc.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT 1. The docs DO state the event is "an opportunity to clean up before termination", but with the catch that "Console functions, or any C run-time functions that call console functions, may not work reliably", which is not an issue in my case. I updated the question to replace the use of `Console.Beep()` 2. You state I can "record except exiting". How would I do that?

Comment: @RobinHartmann For example, you can set a flag (a value stored non-volatile) when the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` received and check it when starts up next time to determine if last exiting is normal or has exception. Set this flag on exiting and clear it after starting up.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I actually had that idea as well. But this doesn't really work in my use case, because the point of my app is to automatically switch to a high performance power plan depending on which applications are running and it needs to switch back to the previous power plan upon exit. Otherwise, the high performance power plan will stay enabled until the next time my app is launched, which defeats the purpose of trying to maximize performance when needed while optimizing power consumption when possible.

Comment: @RobinHartmann While at what condition your application is terminated via Task Manager? By who?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I mean, there's no NEED to terminate the application via Task Manager, but would like to handle all possible ways of termination as far as possible, of course.

Comment: @RobinHartmann Ok. But how the flag (which indicates the way the application terminated) related to your application's performance power plan?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RobinHartmann Because you said *"I actually had that idea as well. But this doesn't really work in my use case, because the point of my app is to automatically switch to a high performance power plan..."* regarding my suggestion of setting a flag.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT You propose I should set a flag in persistent storage upon app start, which I would clear on a successful graceful shutdown. So I can do my cleanup upon my next app start, in case the flag is still there. Similar to how Google Chrome allows you to restore previously opened tabs in case of a crash. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I **could** use this in my case, but it wouldn't really solve my issue. My app is playing the role of a custom power plan manager and is tasked with minimizing power usage unless certain apps are running (it does this by changing the power plan). If I implement your proposal and my app is non-gracefully terminated, the high performance power plan would stay selected until its next launch. This still isn't optimal. Therefore, I'd still like to find a way gracefully exit upon `End Task` (from `Process` tab).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Nevertheless, I will implement the flag, because it allows me to "cleanup" a non-graceful termination in case the app is immediately killed using  `End Task` (from `Details` tab), even though it only allows me to do it upon the next launch. Because as far as I understand, there's no way to handle such an immediate process termination.

Comment: @RobinHartmann Yes, you understand my proposal correctly. Terminating an applicaion from Task Manager is never a graceful action however you are not able to prevent users from doing this. For power plan, for example, you can always starts from low / balanced power plan until you detects the certain apps are running. That is refer to "default" ation in additon to last stored plan upon exiting gracefully.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT You say *Terminating an applicaion from Task Manager is never a graceful action*, but the docs state regarding the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` *A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console [...] by clicking the End Task button command from Task Manager* and that is why I think there should be a way to handle it (at least when it was triggered from the `Process` tab), but I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @RobinHartmann The console can get notification when terminated from Task Manager doesn't prove this kind of terminating is graceful. Like there are `TerminateProcess` / `TerminateThread` but it is not suggested to use them.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Then why does Task Manager even bother sending `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to all the processes attached to the console, if there's no way for them to react to it?

Answer (score 3):

Your marshaling doesn't look quite right. This is what I use:

```
private enum ConsoleControlEvent : uint
{
    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6,
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler_HandlerRoutine(ConsoleControlEvent controlType);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlHandler_HandlerRoutine handler,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool add);
```

Comment: I tried it with your code, but the behavior is still the same, sadly. By the way, can you recommend a site  where I can get more information on how to properly do marshaling or even a full library, which does this for me? I've been using a combination of https://pinvoke.net/ and just defining/converting it myself based on the documentation, until now.

Comment: @RobinHartmann: No, unfortunately. I was planning to write a book on it years ago, but that never happened. It is something of a black art and sites like pinvoke .net are really hit-and-miss.

Comment: I noticed that, as well. What a shame.

Comment: @RobinHartmann: [So, this just happened.](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/01/21/making-win32-apis-more-accessible-to-more-languages/)

Comment: Now that's excellent timing - thanks for sharing!