# How to run code before program exit?

Tags: c#, exit

I have a little console C# program like

```
Class Program 
{ 
    static void main(string args[]) 
    {
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something after main() exit. I tried to write a deconstructor for Class Program, but it never get hit.

Does anybody know how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try the [ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit(v=VS.90).aspx) event of `AppDomain`:

```
using System;
class Test {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler (OnProcessExit); 
        // Do something here
    }

    static void OnProcessExit (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("I'm out of here");
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer was incorrect, this is the best approach.

Comment: This is the most generic solution, but be careful here, as the `ProcessExit` event is time-limited to three seconds (like finalizers are when the application shuts down). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works... First time, then it stopped working! :-(

Comment: will this work even if the user closes the program?

Comment: AppDomain.ProcessExit is not guaranteed to be calledhttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx

Comment: Sure, 'rudely' killing the process will not give a chance to execute ProcessExit. Hence the 'rudely' :-)

Comment: Hitting the X button at the top-right corner of a window can 'rudely' kill the process, for anyone unaware.

Comment: i.e. this answer is entirely useless in a large number of cases.

Comment: Miryafa, this works when we hit the X button at the top right corner of the application. I am using a WPF application and its working for me. Yet to check with a console though.

Comment: This also will not work if the application throws an exception.

Comment: This does not work for me in a console application. I'm using .NET 4.7.2