# C# How to kill process which run using Process.Start() when forced kill my program

Tags: c#, process

I have big problem.
In my code,

```
private void TestFunction()
{
   Process.Start("-other.program.exe");
}
```

and I want to the process kill when my main program is killed.

I can't use `Closed` event handler cause it'll not fire if my program is killed from task manager process list.

I found some keyword such as *fork* and *exec*, but I have not found how to do.

I want to kill the process which start by my program when my program is killed not right way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer given by [Gonzalo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555354/4069539).This way you can hook an action to the end of your programm. In there, you could kill your process by calling `p.Close();` on the `Process`-object.

Comment: It doesn't work. If i close my program by clicking close button, it work. But when I close my program by using **task manager**, it doesn't work.