# Why does handling cancel closing make my .NET application crash?

Tags: .net, events, console, kernel32

I used the answer from this thread:
[Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c)

Whenever I close the console, I get a "--- has stopped working." from Windows 7.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried debugging from there and looked what Exception gets thrown?

Answer (score 1):

1) IMHO, that answer's approach isn't necessarily a good idea - if you know of things you need to clean up that process exit doesn't already clean up for you (for instance, it'll already do connections, file handles, memory, threads, etc), then hooking to the appdomain unload or process exit or similar kind of event is a better idea IMHO

2) how did you implement Handler?  as per the comments in that question, if you had it return true, that explains what you're seeing.