# How to be notified when service stop requested

Tags: c#, windows-services

I got below code from http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2007/08/15/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

When running in console mode, I would like to be notified when service is requested to stop, rather than waiting user input. ( I mean here user requested to stop program via Ctrl+C or by closing console)

It is trivial that when working as a service OnStop is called upon stop request, but how can I implement a workaround so that I can also be notified when working in console mode.

So is there any event that I can subscribe to be notified or any member function etc.?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
-victor

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
public partial class DemoService : ServiceBase
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        DemoService service = new DemoService();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive) // Console mode
        {
            service.OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program");

            Console.Read();

            service.OnStop();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
        } 
    }

    public DemoService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to start your service.
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down

        //necessary to stop your service.
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a watchdog-like pattern, i guess.  Haven't worked with this stuff before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the CancelKeyPress event.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx

Comment: thanks. This redirected me to more comprehensive place
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c