# Capture console exit C# in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, events, console, exit

Does anyone know how to react to the ctrl+c event in a console in c# in windows?

this question: [Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c) says how to do it, but I've tried and it only captures the event when the user click the close X in the top of the console window.

Nothing happens when the user types ctrl+c, it doesn't even hit the handler when debugging.

Thanks

Here is my code

```
namespace EventCloseConsole
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

        private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);
        static EventHandler _handler;

        enum CtrlType
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
        }

        private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
        {
            switch (sig)
            {
                case CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:

                    Console.WriteLine("Closing");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The debugger gets in the way, it looks for Ctrl+C as well. Start your program with Ctrl+F5 to test this.

Answer (score 4):

That works for me on Windows 7. Closing with x-button
the secret is the variable static ConsoleEventDelegate _d

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleEventHooker.Closed += ConsoleEventHooker_Closed;
}

static void ConsoleHooker_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

ConsoleEventHooker.cs

```
namespace System
{
    internal static class ConsoleEventHooker
    {
        private static bool _initedHooker;
        private static EventHandler _closed; 
        private static EventHandler _shutdown;
        private static ConsoleEventDelegate _d;

        public static event EventHandler Closed
        {
            add
            {
                Init();
                _closed += value;
            }
            remove { _closed -= value; }
        }

        public static event EventHandler Shutdown
        {
            add
            {
                Init();
                _shutdown += value;
            }
            remove { _shutdown -= value; }
        }

        private static void Init()
        {
            if (_initedHooker) return;
            _initedHooker = true;
            _d = ConsoleEventCallback;
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_d, true);
        }

        private static bool ConsoleEventCallback(CtrlTypes eventType)
        {
            if (eventType == CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
            {
                if(_closed != null) _closed(null,new EventArgs());
            }

            if (eventType == CtrlTypes.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT)
            {
                if (_shutdown != null) _shutdown(null, new EventArgs());
            }
            return false;
        }

        // A delegate type to be used as the handler routine 
        // for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
        delegate bool ConsoleEventDelegate(CtrlTypes ctrlType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventDelegate callback, bool add);

    }

    // An enumerated type for the control messages
    // sent to the handler routine.
    public enum CtrlTypes
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wire up the Console.CancelKeyPress  event to a handler.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a great article on the topic.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work for me, I copied and pasted the code directly into a new console app. I noticed this was written in 2006, could it be because I'm using windows 7?

Comment: That should be correct can you add the code you tried to your question. should just have to add  Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(myHandler); to your main method

Comment: That link is broken now.

Comment: Added an msdn link instead.