# how can i disable close button of console window in a visual studio console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I need to disable the close button in the console window of a visual studio console 
application written in C#. I want that the application should run until it completes
and the user should not be able to stop it by closing the console window. I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: You will also need to block right-click on the application in the taskbar and select 'close'. And maybe the taskmanager?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is an example to disable close button on console window:

```
class Program
{
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false),SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about rightclick on the application in the taskbar and then select close?

Comment: Thanks.Works like a charm.Although, as PowerRoy pointed out,  the console window can still be closed from the task bar, I am happy with the given solution.Could you please briefly explain what the code is actually doing ?

Comment: @vjain27: Everything is in msdn :) [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Retrieves the window handle used by the console associated with the calling process. [GetSystemMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Returns handle to windows menu. And [DeleteMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647629%28VS.85%29.aspx) Deletes specified menu item. And finally constants you can find [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.deletemenu).

Comment: @PowerRoy: Somewhere I read that its hard to do it. But maybe its posible - I dont know :) Maybe you can try to send your app to system tray?