# Disable the maximize and minimize buttons of a c# console

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have looked around for disabling the 'control' bar of a c# application. It's very similar to
[how can i disable close button of console window in a visual studio console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052992/how-can-i-disable-close-button-of-console-window-in-a-visual-studio-console-appl)

However I also wish to apply this to the minimize and maximize buttons. I'm not sure whats going on with the code from the previous explanation so that may be my issue in applying it to all the buttons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is a solution :

```
 class Program
    {
        private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
        public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This worked a charm! Thank you, and I can see the differences that has kind of helped me to understand what's happening

Comment: Consider adding a link to msdn where you found the values for SC_MINIMIZE and SC_MAXIMIZE so your answer backed by the official docs.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this code, i hope it will work for either go through my given link
below

```
internal static class WindowExtensions
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int value);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    internal static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(this Window window)
    {
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

        IntPtr hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & -131073 & -65537));

    }
}

this.SourceInitialized += (x, y) =>
{
    this.HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons();
};
```

Other Link: 
[Link Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269129/Csharp-Forms-Close-Button-Example)

Comment: This code doesn't work on a console project as there is no `Window` on `this`, what ever this is in your context

Comment: If I'm correct this is for a WPF rather than a console application?