# How do i prevent resising of the console in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, console

I need to prevent the user of my console program from resizing the window, only allowing it to be changed programmatically. If the user changes the width or hight, everything messes up. Also, I want to therefore disable/remove the maximise button. I belive that it was previously possible in VB.Net 2015 [[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175206/how-to-prevent-the-console-window-being-resized-in-vb-net)]. However everything i am seeing is outdated and doesn't work.

I also need to prevent resizing of the window when it is snapped to a corner.

This was the old VB.Net code:

```
`Module Module1

    Private Const MF_BYCOMMAND As Integer = &H0
    Public Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = &HF060
    Public Const SC_MINIMIZE As Integer = &HF020
    Public Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = &HF030
    Public Const SC_SIZE As Integer = &HF000

    Friend Declare Function DeleteMenu Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal nPosition As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
    Friend Declare Function GetSystemMenu Lib "user32.dll" (hWnd As IntPtr, bRevert As Boolean) As IntPtr


    Sub Main()

        Dim handle As IntPtr
        handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess.MainWindowHandle ' Get the handle to the console window

        Dim sysMenu As IntPtr
        sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, False) ' Get the handle to the system menu of the console window

        If handle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND) ' To prevent user from closing console window
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND) 'To prevent user from minimizing console window
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND) 'To prevent user from maximizing console window
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND) 'To prevent the use from re-sizing console window
        End If

        Do Until (Console.ReadKey.Key = ConsoleKey.Escape)
            'This loop keeps the console window open until you press escape      
        Loop

    End Sub

End Module
`
```

I have also considered using `console.setbuffersize` but wouldn't know how to have the programm continually set the buffer to that size as my program is across a lot of subroutines.

Comment: Console programs don't even get to assume they are running in a window at all.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent the console window from being resized by the user. First, add this into your module:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Function MoveWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer, ByVal bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>
Friend Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rect As RECT) As Boolean
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure RECT
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer
End Structure
```

Then in your `Main` sub add this code, before anything else:

```
Dim CurrentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
Dim hWnd As IntPtr = CurrentProcess.MainWindowHandle
Dim RECT As New RECT()
GetWindowRect(hWnd, RECT)
Dim Width As Integer = RECT.Right - RECT.Left
Dim Height As Integer = RECT.Bottom - RECT.Top
Dim X As Integer = RECT.Left
Dim Y As Integer = RECT.Top
Dim WorkerThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                 While (True)
                                                     MoveWindow(CurrentProcess.MainWindowHandle, X, Y, Width, Height, True)
                                                 End While
                                             End Sub)
WorkerThread.Start()
```

This will allow the program to change the width, height or position of the window, by changing the values of the variables. Here is an example:

```
Width = 200
Height = 150
```

You would place that somewhere else in the `Main` sub.

I assume that your using a `.Net Framework`, not `.Net Core`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, may i ask which version of Visual Studio you are running as the hwnd is retreiving no value for me and therefore doesn't work? I am using .NET Framework.

Comment: I am using `.net framework 4.7.2` and visual studio 2022 version `17.4.1`

Comment: Are you using windows 11 or 10 ?

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Therefore a windows 11 issuee with their updated terminal, thanks for your time.