# Prevent Console window from killing the process

Tags: c#, vb.net, console, smallbasic

I am adding the debugging functionality to [Small Visual Basic language](https://github.com/VBAndCs/sVB-Small-Visual-Basic) (written with VB .NET), which I built on top of MS Small Basic (Written with C#).
I have two issues:

Issue 1:
The SB/sVB TextWindow represents the Console window, and it works fine when it is accessed from a separate process (like running the exe files compiled by the language), but it has troubles in the debug mode.
The TextWindow (Console) doesn't work in debug mode. It is inactive and user can't write into it.
The code uses win32 APIs to show the console, then uses the System.Console class method to interact with it. In WinForms and WPF project, this will interact with Output Window not the console window.
This is the exception I get when I try to read a key:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.

**Edit:**
I found a solution for this issue:
I discovered that the console window doesn't work when I run the sVB project in VS .NET in debugging mode, but if I run it without debugging, or launch the sVB.EXE outside VS .NET, the console window works, and this is fine with me.
So, issue 1 is already solved, but issue 2 still needs a solution.

Issue 2:
The console window terminates the whole process when it is closed, and I can't find a way to prevent that. I've read similar topics here, but I couldn't find a proper solution. For example, disabling the close button is not a full solution, because user can still press Ctrl+C. I also tried using the SetConsoleCtrlHandler to and intercept the close event, but I couldn't cancel terminating the process.
Note that closing the process while running in the debugging mode closes sVB itself! This is also an issue when running any app.exe as closing the console while other windows are open will close them all!

Is there any solution for these issues?
And if not, can I  use a normal window for the TextWindow, and if so how to make the code execution wait for the return of the Read methods until the user submits his input in such a window?
Thanks.

Comment: After reading the information in the URL you've provided, I am left wondering why a child needs to learn to write computer programs and why anyone would need to  create a _new_ computer language because the child isn't developed enough to grasp the concepts? Educational curriculums often contain an introduction to computers at what the educators have determined to be an _appropriate_ age. I'm not sure that your _Small Visual Basic language_ programming language is needed.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680382/how-do-i-get-output-from-a-command-to-appear-in-a-control-on-a-form-in-real-time

Comment: I am not sure I got what objections about sVB. Why are Scratch and Small Basic created? In my experience, they are not best for the job, so I am trying to introduce programming to kids in a more enjoyable and productive way. I wrote [a book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CVK1BMC9) for 6 years old kids to show that using UI with text code is the easier than block coding and that SB text window. Above that, sVB gives more to SB devs that never moved on to a higher language, and makes it easy for them to move on to VB .NET (and C# later if they want).

Comment: And by the way, not all curricula are the same in the world. For example, in Egypt Scratch is introduced in the 7 grade and VB .NET in the 9th grade, which is not logical for me, and as the result kids learn nothing from this! Kids (and teachers) need something easier to start with in elementary schools. I am writing a series of books to show that is possible. But note that age of 6 for native English kids may mean 8 or 9 for non native English speakers.

Comment: 6 year olds should be playing outside with their peers learning social interaction, not spending all of their time alone on a computer. _Social skills_ , including learning how to develop interpersonal relationships, set boundaries, etc..., are far more important than developing _computer skills_. These days it seems that educators are pushing kids to learn more at a younger age. What are they going to do with all this _advanced_ knowledge? Often times the happiest people are the ones who, by educational standards, don't know so much.

Comment: The information in the URL should help you with your issue. If not, you'll have to re-write your post because it's not completely clear what you're doing or attempting to do with the _Console_ window. Also, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: I agree with the importance of physical and social activities, and always advice to less exposure of kids to screens, and gave instructions in the book that it should be introduced in 1-2 hours in weekends over an entire year. But science is complected and since machines took most of human jobs a century ago, we had to loose third of our lives in schools to learn how to operate machines and do other things that they can't. The worst is AI will take most of our renaming jobs, and I expect that the next generation will need to master electronics, high math and programming to find something to do

Comment: I read the post you linked, but it doesn't fix my issue, because I don't deal with the cmd.exe and don't want to fire a new process to be able to debug code lines. 
In fact I found a solution for the first issue:
I discovered that the console window doesn't work when I run the sVB project in VS .NET in debugging mode, but if I run it without debugging, or launch the sVB.EXE outside VS .NET, the console window works, and this is fine with me.
So, issue 1 is already solved, but issue 2 still needs a solution: how to prevent the consol from killing the process?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the first issue:
I discovered that the console window doesn't work when I run the sVB project in VS .NET in debugging mode, but if I run it without debugging, or launch the sVB.EXE outside VS .NET, the console window works, and this is fine with me. I wish if VS debugger can solve this issue, but I can live with it.
So, issue 1 can be considered solved.

Regarding issue 2:
Currently. I just disabled the close button of the console window as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052992/how-can-i-disable-close-button-of-console-window-in-a-visual-studio-console-appl), so, the user will have to press any key to close the window, but the code will actually hide it unless it is the last opened window in the project. This is a good workaround, but the user can still press Ctrl+C to close the window. In fact this is not likely specially by kids and adults that use sVB, so, I will live with this, until someone comes with a full solution.
The code I used in the project exists in the [TextWindow.Show](https://github.com/VBAndCs/sVB-Small-Visual-Basic/blob/9602c42d879969fcaafdc54d3b80ff8b3d163be3/SmallBasicLibrary/Library/TextWindow.vb#L155) method, and the related APIs exist in the [NativeHelper class](https://github.com/VBAndCs/sVB-Small-Visual-Basic/blob/master/SmallBasicLibrary/Library.Internal/NativeHelper.vb).
Thanks.