# C# Console App Not Calling Finally Block

Tags: c#, console-application, try-finally

I'm writing a console app to run as a scheduled task and it doesn't appear to execute the finally block of the running code when you close it using the close button. I've tried to replicate this behaviour with the following very simple console app:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run through the debugger this doesn't hit a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine` line. I'm not sure if this simple test works as intended or why the finally block doesn't appear to run in either this test or my production code.

I thought finally blocks *always* run (isn't that the whole point of them?). What is going on here?

Comment: It turns out what I need to do is use the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c/474743#474743

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A finally block will *always* run unless the process itself terminates abruptly - which is what's happening here. It's not like `Thread.Sleep` is throwing an exception, and the stack is unwinding gracefully - the whole process is just being aborted. At least as far as I can tell :)

Comment: @Mitch: Not sure about that - it's new to me.

Comment: @Jon: Is there any sensible way to close down gracefully (e.g. release unmanaged resources) on a close button click?

Comment: @Jackson: I don't know of anything in this case - there may well be something, but I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out what I needed to do was copy the code from this answer: [Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c/474743#474743)