# ConsoleCancelEventHandler - can't enter it when Ctrl+C is pressed

Tags: c#

My C# project contains such code:

```
    public static void ConsoleCancelEventHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bExit = true;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += ConsoleCancelEventHandler;
```

It's probably not brilliant code style. But my quesion would be - why it doesn't work. After I've added C++ CLI project to my solution I can not go to `ConsoleCancelEventHandler`. I press `Ctrl+C` but nothing happens. Why? How can I handle `Ctrl+C` to correctly exit application?

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" do you mean that you've debugged your code, and the event handler isn't hit? Or do you mean that you don't know if it's hit or not?

Comment: I mean that breakpoint at `bExit=true` is not activated in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the .NET handler isn't working, but [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should work:

[Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp/474743#474743)