# Kill processes that I'm monitoring if the main application is closed

Tags: c#, console-application

I have an application that launches another program and monitors it. When the program closes, my application also closes.

However, if I close my application first, the other program is still running.

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myProg.exe");
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
proc.Start();

while (!proc.HasExited)
{
    // do stuff
}

// On proc exit, my application is also done
```

How do I make sure that if I close my monitoring app, any processes that are being monitored are also killed?

So for example suppose MyApp is monitoring Notepad.
If I close MyApp, Notepad should also be closed.

Comment: Hook the `OnClose` or `OnUnload` event of your main form, and kill the process that you are monitoring.

Comment: Is this a Console or Form application? That will make a large difference into what you need to do in order to detect that your app is being exited.

Comment: Console, though I am planning to create a form application so both would be nice to know. For the purposes of this question it is a console app.

Comment: FWIW, the proper way to do this is to use a Windows Job Object (this will require PInvoke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a console application, capturing the "Exit" event is a bit trickier than forms. Take a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp) thread, I have it bookmarked because I was wondering the same thing as you a long time ago and it's handy to keep this around.

Answer (score 0):

At that end of your program call:

```
if (!proc.HasExited)
    proc.CloseMainWindow();
```

... to close the other process's window.

Comment: It is what he asked: he wants to close the *other* process's window. The other process being "proc".

Comment: Yes; but not if he closes his application first which he also wanted.

Comment: Evidently, his question was in fact: "how can I detect a console application is being closed" and not how to kill a monitored process. I read it mainly as the latter.