# How to process console application closing

Tags: c#, console-application

We do have console application:

```
namespace MyApplication
{

    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit  += (sender, eventArgs) => Stop();

            Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    public void Start() 
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So if application is stopped proper (by pressing `Enter` in console window) `Close()` method is called from `finally` & `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`

But when application is closed by `Close button` or terminated from `Task Manager` `Close()` method is not called at all.

Questions are:

1. Why `finally` block doesn't work?
2. How to handle console closing by `Close button`?

**UPD**
Even object's destructor is not called:

```
public class Watcher
{
    Action _start;
    Action _stop;
    public Watcher(Action start, Action stop)
    {
        _start = start;
        _stop = stop;
    }

    ~Watcher()
    {
        _stop();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _start();
    }
}

// And using as:
var w = new Watcher(Start, Stop);
w.Start();
```

Destructor is not called!

Comment: Please refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. The finally block is only reached when the `Console.ReadLine()` call is completed which only happens when you press enter on the keyboard. There is no other way to reach the code in the finally block.
2. To handle the `close button` you will need to subscribe to the Win32 event as .NET does not provide direct bindings for it. Please see suggestions in this question: [Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp)