# Wait for timer or event, whichever happens soonest

Tags: c#, .net, signals

I have what is currently a single-threaded console app which does something every 30s... e.g.

```
while(exitFlagNotSet)
{
 doStuff();
 Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

However I'd also like to listen for application-exit a bit along the lines of [Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp). In such a situation I can't wait 30s - my app will be forcibly terminated after 5s IIRC.

So is there a way to refactor my approach so the 30s wait may be aborted when something occurs? I've done this kind of thing in C++ but don't know what the terminology and techniques are in C#/.net

Comment: Use a Timer so there isn't anything that *needs* to be aborted.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. This would be simpler, I just need to decide if it's useful detecting the exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WaitHandle` of `CancellationToken` to do that:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;
    EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(sig => {
        // may want to investigate signal here
        // cancel if appropriate
        cts.Cancel();
        return true;
    });
    // this is from your linked answer
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, true);

    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) {
        Console.WriteLine("doing stuff");
        var cancelled = token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(30000);
        if (cancelled) {
            // handle exit
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When calncelled - `WaitHandle` of `CancellationToken` will be signalled, and as such `WaitOne` returns true. If `WaitOne` exited because of timeout - it returns false.

Comment: I don't know if this is correct but in my tests I did `while(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)` which made things more elegant

Comment: @MrBoy sure, that's just example of how to wait until timeout or cancelled, while (true) is not relevant.