# Inventor COM object not released when created with Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, comobject, autodesk-inventor, running-object-table

My problem is this:
If Autodesk Inventor is not running, my app (console app) creates a new instance with `Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);` and uses it as a COM object. When my app does not quit Inventor but leaves it open and the user later quits it by hand there is still a process *inventor.exe* running in TaskManager which can only be killed in TaskManager.
Curiously the problem only arises when these two things are combined. Whenever my app quits Inventor with `InventorApp.Quit();` it is closed properly and there is no process left open.

If my app starts Inventor with `Process.Start(..);` or the user starts Inventor before starting the app and then my app grabs Inventor with `Marshal.GetActiveObject(ProgId);` there is no problem no matter if the app or the user quits Inventor.

If my app starts Inventor with `Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);` then leaves Inventor open, the app is closed and then restarted, it grabs Inventor with `Marshal.GetActiveObject(..);` and then quits Inventor via `InventorApp.Quit();` there is no problem.

So, the problem with the left open process only arises in this specific combination:

1. start Inventor via `Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);`
2. the user quits Inventor by hand

The left open process is not in the Running Object Table anymore so it can't be handled as a COM object anymore and it has no visible UI, which means it can only be killed in TaskManager.

Using the 'bad combination' as described I even tried to call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` several times (I know this is bad but I am just trying everything) in different combinations and before and/or after `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(invApp); Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(invApp);`. I even tried a minimal app which literally does nothing else. See below for the code.

So, what is `Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);` doing that is causing this? Is there any way to prevent this? Or is this a problem specific to Inventor?

**Minimal app example:**

```
        Inventor.Application invApp = null;
        string ProgId = "Inventor.Application";
        try
        {
            invApp = (Inventor.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject(ProgId);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            try
            {

                Type InventorType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgId);
                invApp = (Inventor.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1);
                Console.WriteLine(e2);
            }
        }

        invApp = invApp as Inventor.Application;
        invApp.Visible = true;

        Console.Write("Quit Inventor? (y/n) ");
        string quit = Console.ReadLine();
        if (quit == "y")
        {
            invApp.Quit();
        }

        // desperately trying to release the COM object ...
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        if (invApp != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(invApp);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(invApp);
        }
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        if (invApp != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(invApp);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(invApp);
        }
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        invApp = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific for Inventor but for any COM object (Excel for example).

Usually I don't use this COM communication for production, because there are many vulnerabilities and some performance issues. I recommend you to use another workflow when possible.
But to your question. You can't release this COM object as you try. I recommend you to wrap `Inventor.Application` to some `IDisposable` object and quit them in dispose method, when you create your own instance.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InventorTest();

    //Waiting for dispose message
    //Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void InventorTest()
{
    using (var invProvider = new InventorDisposableProvider())
    {

        var invApp = invProvider.InventorApp;

        invApp.Visible = true;

        Console.Write("Quit Inventor? (y/n) ");
        string quit = Console.ReadLine();
        if (quit == "y")
        {
            invApp.Quit();
        }

    }
}

class InventorDisposableProvider : IDisposable
{
    private Application invApp;
    private bool startedByMe = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets running or start new instance of Inventor
    /// </summary>
    public Application InventorApp
    {
        get
        {
            if (invApp == null) GetInventorApp();

            return invApp;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (startedByMe && invApp != null)
        {
            invApp .Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Quit");
        }
    }

    private void GetInventorApp()
    {
        string ProgId = "Inventor.Application";
        try
        {
            invApp = (Inventor.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject(ProgId);
            startedByMe = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            try
            {
                Type InventorType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgId);
                invApp = (Inventor.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(InventorType);
                startedByMe = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1);
                Console.WriteLine(e2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but it is a good start point.

I found only one issue. When user quit the console application by cross. In this case you can see this article how to solve this case.
[capture-console-exit-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately the result is still the same when I uncomment the line 'startedByMe = true' so that Inventor is left open after quitting the app (and not typing "y"). There is still a process Inventor.exe in TaskManager when the user quits Inventor by hand, even with the IDisposable interface. (I copied your code as it is and tested it directly on my machine.)

Comment: There is no defense against proactive users. :-( You can try to prevent Inventor from closing, but I don't know how. Or you can clean processes using this simple call ```Process.Start("taskkill.exe", @"/F /IM inventor.exe /T");``` But it closes all Inventors without possibility to save any work.