# Call cancel on thread when pressing ctrl+c

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console

I've written a console application that basically fires one BackgroundWorker that supports ReportProgress and Cancel.

How can I make sure that before a window is closed (by pressing the close button or pressing ctrl+c) the cancel operation is triggered on my thread and the window only closes after the cancel is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question "[How do I trap ctrl-c in a C# console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-console-app)."