# atexit, exit delegate in c#

Tags: c#, exit

In c++ there is a function called [atexit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/) where you can register functions which should be run when the system exits. Are there any similar events in C#?

UPDATE:
The AppDomain.ProcessExit doesn't seem to catch Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break. Anyone knows anything about that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the [`ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) and [`DomainUnload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) events of the [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) class.

Comment: Doesn't seem to catch Ctrl-C though. Know anything about that?

Comment: @Mats: CTRL+C seems to close the process in some way that will not raise these events. That particular key combination do however raise the Console.CancelKeyPress event. So a combination of AppDomain.ProcessExit and Console.CancelKeyPress should cover most exit scenarios, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Application.ApplicationExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) event if you've a WinForms application. For WPF there's [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx).

Comment: I know how to shut down applications, I'm interested in how to attach events to when that happens. Thanks anyway tho.

Comment: Sorry, the one about the console app was wrong (I edited that). The two remaining references are events occuring when you exit your app (WinForm/WPF).

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately I need it in console mode.. Probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answers to this may help you:

- [How do I trap ctrl-c in a C# console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-console-app)

Comment: So probably need to catch both events then, the ProcessExit and the ConsoleCancelEventHandler. Would be neat with just one event that's always called. Well, well..

Comment: Could be. But that shouldn't be much of a problem, just do whatever you need to do in a separate method which is called by both eventhandlers or something :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a WinForms app you can add a listener to the `Application.ApplicationExit` event