# Run code when current process terminates?

Tags: c#, process

Is there a way to run a bit of code when the current process is getting terminated?

I want to log some stuff when a process terminates (either through external means - eg killing it - or quitting in the application itself).

We're talking about a Console application written in c#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here: [atexit, exit delegate in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679876/atexit-exit-delegate-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but something similar would help

```
Process process = new Process();
.
.
process.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
process.Start();

private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{    
  eventHandled = true;
  customAction(); // your logging stuff here
}
public void customAction()
{
  //
}
```

---

have a look at: [**Process.Exited Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx)

Comment: I'm not starting a process. I need to know when the current process is about to go the way of the dodo.