# Azure DevOps Server: How to prevent 'Access to path is denied' when initalizing a job?

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-devops-server-2019

I am using [Azure DevOps Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops) (ADOS for short, installed on-premises) to run end to end tests based on Selenium in C#.

Every now and then a build ends badly without properly stopping the [`chromedriver.exe`](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) process used by my Selenium tests. As a result, the subsequent build fails at the *Initialize Job* step with an error that looks like this:

> One or more errors occurred. (Access to path 'C:...\chromedriver.exe' is denied.)

What I understand from this is that because `chromedriver.exe` is still running ADOS cannot delete its `.exe` file when it tries to clean the working folder at the start of the build run.

I've tried disabling the *Clean* feature of the *Get sources* step definition but that only shifted the error a bit forward to the *Checkout* step.

To resolve the problem I am forced to manually RDP into my agent machine, `taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F` and re-run the failed build.

**My question is** - How can I prevent the access denied error? I've thought of these approaches but I'm not sure which is practical:

1. Get ADOS to run `taskkill` automatically before the *Get sources* step. How?
2. Make the agent have higher privileges so it can delete `chromedriver.exe` even when its process is still running. Again, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your assumption is correct:

> What I understand from this is that because `chromedriver.exe` is still running ADOS cannot delete its `.exe` file when it tries to clean the working folder at the start of the build run.

Make sure you are using the `driver.close()` as well as the `driver.quit()` methods at the end of every test.

Use teardown to make sure it will always happen.

## EDIT:

As OP commented:

> when I cancel the ADOS build, the test step is terminated abruptly and the teardown step is not executed.

My recommendation is to an `atexit` method.

For C# Use [ProcessExit Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=netframework-4.8) (credit to [@Fredrik Mörk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93623/fredrik-m%c3%b6rk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679888/6845383))

For Python use [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)

Comment: Thanks @moshe-slavin. I'm actually calling those method but if I understand correctly then when I cancel the ADOS build, the test step is terminated abruptly and the teardown step is not executed.

Comment: @urig what language are you using for the `selenium` scripts? if you use `python`... you can use the `atexit`  [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html).

Comment: @urig You can find some ways todo it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679888/6845383)

Comment: I'll give the exit events approach a try next week and let you know how it worked. thanks

Comment: Hope you'll find it helpful! Shabat shalom

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution based on ADOS Pipelines' functionality. After my Visual Studio Test task I've added a [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and configured it like so:

1. The *script* is '[`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)`/IM chromedriver.exe /F`'.
2. Under *Control Options* I've set:

   - *Run this task* to *'Custom conditions'*
   - *Custom condition* to '[`canceled()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#canceled)'
   - *Continue on error* checked.

This way, whenever my build is cancelled manually, all instances of the `chromedriver.exe` process are terminated, clearing the way for subsequent builds to run.