# Platform independent way to catch console/terminal close event

Tags: c++, c++11, console, cross-platform, platform-independent

My question simply is:

> Is it possible to catch and process console/terminal closing event platform independently?

My question isn't the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546509/detect-when-console-application-is-closing-killed), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696117/what-happens-when-you-close-a-c-console-application). None of the answers on these questions provide a platform independent way. So, is there any way? If yes, then what is it? Or is it flat impossible? If so, why is that? I mean, why is it not possible to develop a library that could handle this?

**EDIT:** As @Yakk asked, I need it to work on both Windows and Linux, with the least code repetition possible. If it helps, I'm learning basic networking. I've built a simple chat app, in which I need to add entries in a chat history file while closing the app. I've implemented a way to close it from inside the app. But, as users are more likely to click the close button, I need to be able that event to do the operations.

Comment: Do you mean  "is it in the standard"?  Or "is there a library that does this?"  The first is easy.  No.  The second is easy.  Off-topic for SO.  Another question is "how can I catch and process the console/terminal closing event on every single C++ platform that exists or can exist?", which is too broad.  Can you make a *concrete* and *narrow* question, such as "I need to be able to catch the console/terminal closing event on the following platforms, how do I do it with the least code repetition" followed by a list of platforms?

Comment: @Yakk Basically, I need it to work on both Windows Linux.

Comment: @Yakk And also, if I need to ask about such a library, which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do so, and I am not aware of a library available, but it is not that hard to write it yourself:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
static void (*theHandler)(int);
static BOOL WINAPI winHandler(DWORD ctrlType)
{
    theHandler((int)ctrlType);
    return TRUE;
}
#endif

void installConsoleHandler(void (*handler)(int))
{
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
    theHandler = handler;
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(&winHandler, TRUE);
#else
    /* sigaction, as you find in your links */
#endif
}
```

If you keep this code, you might extend it later for other platforms:

```c
#if windows
#elif linux || compatible
#elif whatever
#else
#error "not implemented for current platform"
#endif
```

and you get a real library...

The code above is usable in C and C++ (for this I preferred `static` over an anonymous namespace...), so you can place it in a .c file (and compile it as C). To make it work in C++ again (as you requested), you need to tell the C++ compiler that it is a C function (meaning that there is no name mangling as in C++, which would otherwise be applied and thus the function not found during linkage), so the header would contain:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    void installConsoleHandler(void (*handler)(int));
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

(Sure, you did not ask for C, but if you can get it *almost* for free (except for the `extern "C"` stuff), why not take it along? One never knows...)

Comment: Oh, and feel free to find a better name for the function. Don't really like it myself...

Comment: Seems like it's the only way. Sad there isn't a general way. Anyways, it is quite acceptable. Thanks a lot.