# How can i get the Ctrl+C as input in console

Tags: c#, console

I want to use ctrl+c as input in console. I can **disable** the ctrl+c to terminate console. But i cannot use the ctrl+c to get input. how can i get the ctrl+c as input????

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
{
     var isctrlc = e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC;
     if (isctrlc)
     {
     e.Cancel = true;
     }
};

k = Console.ReadKey(true);
if((k.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
{
   if((k.Key & ConsoleKey.C)!=0)
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trap ctrl-c in a C# console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-sharp-console-app)

Comment: But here i want to get the Ctrl+C to break my code. i cannot reach the break. how can i change the code i want to stop the loop when i enter the Ctrl+C as input.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can set e.Cancel=true; in CancelKeyPress event handler. I have tested the following code snippet. It works.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine("..");
            }
        }


        private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Cancel key trapped. Execution will not terminate.");
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

You can use following property to achieve what you want.

```
Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

        while (true)
        {
            var k = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if ((k.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
            {
                if ((k.Key & ConsoleKey.C) != 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("..");
        }
```

Comment: I can stop the termination when Ctrl+C entered. Here i want to know how can i break the loop using Ctrl+C.

Comment: You can use Console.TreatControlCAsInput property.