# How to make a countdown timer while waiting for multiple user inputs

Tags: c#, timer, user-input

I am making a console maths project where the user answers multiple maths questions.

I am trying to add a countdown timer but I can't find how to make a timer that will stop once the user answers all the questions;

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use some sort of graphical user interface technology.  Doing it in a console app would be an interesting challenge, but a very frustrating one..  If you want some ideas about how to write a complicated console app (alas, it doesn't consider this case), take a look at my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431607/exit-console-app-at-any-time-during-any-input-c

Comment: It would be great to understand what you want the timer to actually do. It's unclear what a timer's purpose is that would stop after all of the questions are answered. Is it just that someone has 30 seconds to answer all 10 questions, that sort of thing?

Comment: I've looked in your code. You're doing some bad things. You should never do `timerThread.Abort()`. Also `while (DateTime.Now < whenToStop) { /* ... */ Thread.Sleep(1000); }` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers, ProgressBars and similar do not work that well in Console. This addition would be almost trivial in a GUI technology. But doing it in Console requires jumping through hoops. And probably do a major redesign.

The main issue is that you need to be able to *receive* input, but without *blocking* code excution. The conventional Console read methods are all blocking to the last. However there is a workaround. A way to wait for input without blocking:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620647/3346583

Comment: You can use `System.Threading.Timer` in a Console with no problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity Which helps nothing, if you can display the progressing countdown or progress bar.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easy replace your `Thread` code with a `System.Threading.Timer` based version.

I refactored your code in your GutHub: https://github.com/CrazyDanyal1414/mathstester.git

```
public class RunWithTimer
{
    private DateTime _finish { get; set; }
    public bool IsTimeLeft { get=> _finish > DateTime.Now; }

    private System.Threading.Timer _timer = null;

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        string timeLeft = (_finish - DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        WriteToScreen($"Time Remaining: {timeLeft}", true);
        if (!this.IsTimeLeft)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public RunWithTimer(int numberOfSeconds)
    {
        _finish = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(numberOfSeconds);
        _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    }
    public void StopTimer(int numberOfQuestionsLeft)
    {
        if (numberOfQuestionsLeft == 0)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally your `RunWithTimer` would implement `IDisposable` since it holds a variable of `IDisposable`. You'd then remove the `StopTimer` code and `Dispose()` of the it once the questions are finished.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/tutorial-2-create-a-timed-math-quiz?view=vs-2019) should help you. Though the example is a windows forms app, you can use the Timer class to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please do not link to external content without putting the salient parts of that content in your answer itself. You should always write answers that would stand-alone if the link became broken in the future.