# How to implement a exception code for key Interrupt like Ctrl+C in C#

Tags: c#, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I need your help in implementing an exception code with 'try ~ catch' in C#.

My motive is to follow 'try ~ except' in python like below:

```py
try: 
    pass 

except KeyboardInterrupt as e: 
    print("Closed...") 
    break
```

I thought there was also the interrupt exception keyword like Python in C#. 
So, I tried like:

```cpp
try 
{
    // pass 
}
catch (ThreadInterruptedException e) 
{
    Console.Write("Closed...");
    break;
}
```

But, this C# code couldn't catch the interrupt signal by ctrl+C. 
 
I assumed 'ThreadInterruptedException' is for that, but it isn't. 

Which keyword should I use?

I have tried to google, but there are a number of examples about 'how to get 'ctrl+v' value through my console.

Comment: Have you seen [how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-sigint-in-a-c-sharp-console-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-sigint-in-a-c-sharp-console-app) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Console.CancelKeyPress.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netframework-4.8