# How to avoid Console.Write after Ctrl-C during Console.ReadLine?

Tags: .net, .net-core, console-application

I have a small .NET console program that asks for SQL credentials (login, password). The problem is that if I key <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> during login prompt (`string userId = Console.ReadLine();` below), the program stops but `"password:"` prompt is written to the console. Relevant fragment:

```cs
Console.Write("login: ");
string userId = Console.ReadLine();
    
Console.Write("password: ");
```

Output on Ctrl-C during login prompt:

> login: password:

How can I avoid executing subsequent the `Console.Write("password: ");` after exiting with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>?

**UPDATE 1:** CancelKeyPress event handler doesn't help. At least for me, it works for Console.ReadKey, but not for Console.ReadLine: password prompt is still written.

**UPDATE 2:** If there is Write/WriteLine after null-check block, it's still executed on my machine (Win10, VS2019). So, the question in fact remains. Current workaround - ReadKey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trap ctrl-c (SIGINT) in a C# console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-sigint-in-a-c-sharp-console-app)

Comment: @kraego No. I added a note to question about it.

Comment: I ran this code on my machine and the process exits immediately after I press **Ctrl-C**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AgentFire mentioned add input validation.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("login: ");
            string userId = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId))
            {
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
            Console.Write("password: ");
            ....
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but Write after check still executes for me (added a note). Apparently, I'll move on with ReadKey.

Comment: One way, could be to invert the logic as i did in the edit of my answer - end program when input is null or empty (maybe not so good for diagnostics). Or add checks for all inputs, or as you mentioned use ReadKey ....

Answer (score 0):

If your code indeed continues to run after you press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (which it doesn't on my machine for some reason), I would bet ten bucks that your `userId` variable would be `null`, instead of the usual empty string (if you input nothing and press Enter).

So, just check for `null`.

Comment: Thank you, but Write after check still executes for me (added a note). Apparently, I'll move on with ReadKey.