# Is it possible to stop a console application cleanly?

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-4.8

I have a console application I'm developing that can be ran a few ways during development.

**1. From the IDE in debug (Debugger.IsAttached):**

Which gives me a command window that pops up blank and catches keypresses that I wait for using `key = Console.ReadKey();`.  Using this I can cleanly shutdown the console app by pressing the ESC key and do cleanup when it shuts down.  It outputs the `Console.WriteLine()` text to the `Output` window in the IDE.

**2. From the command line in a "Command Prompt" Window:**

Which gives me the output for my `Console.WriteLine()` calls to the same "Command Prompt" window.  It does not seem to catch the ESC key being pressed and the only way I can get the app to stop is to press Ctrl+C.  This kills the application instantly and does not process the cleanup code I want to run before the app exits.

Is it possible to somehow exit the application when not debugging with the IDE (running as a compiled application in a command prompt)?  I would like to have the second example above to be able to shutdown like the first if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrlc-sigint-in-a-c-sharp-console-app

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White that will work for me.  So I guess there is no way to catch the keypress ESC itself in a command prompt huh?